# Wordpress and wp_deregister_script

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to prevent all of the different scripts from my shop ( jigoshop ) from loading on every page load. I have been using the `wp_deregister_script` function but it wont work. My question is, if there is a way that the `wp_deregister_script` function could be blocked by the plugin itself or any other function?

This is the script i am currently using:

```
function js_css_control() 
{
    $link = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $teile = explode("/", $link);
    if($link!="/")
    {
        $seite = $teile[1];
    }
    else
    {
        $seite = "start";
    }
    if($seite=="start")
    {
        wp_deregister_script( 'jigoshop_global' ); 
        wp_deregister_script( 'prettyPhoto' );  
        wp_deregister_style ( 'jigoshop_styles' );
        wp_deregister_style ( 'jigoshop-jquery-ui' );
        wp_deregister_style ( 'jigoshop-select2' );     
    }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'js_css_control');
```

Comment: Please post the code you're using. We can't suggest the reason something may not be working without seeing the way you're attempting it.

Comment: @NathanDawson I just edited my question. Sorry i did not think of this before.

Answer (score 1):

The function that may suit your purpose better is [`wp_dequeue_script`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dequeue_script). You can do everything just about the same except change deregister to dequeue.

Also, if that doesn't work and for future reference, try changing the hook that you use in [`add_action`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference), for instance `template_redirect` may be a choice in case `wp_enqueue_scripts` doesn't pan out.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I just tried the wp_dequeue_script and it did nothing. I honestly don'r understand the remplate_redirect part. But i will try to figure it out.

Comment: If you use the code you wrote, however  change the first parameter passed to add_action to 'template_redirect' I believe it will work. Try it and let me know!